# want to show three view in vertical fashion using dynamically in android

Tags: java, android

My requirement is, I want show three view(i.e. ImageView,TextView,TextView) dynamically in a vertical fashion.

I did like the below program. but its not working.Can any one help me.Please see the below code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
    final ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setId(100+i);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            relativeLayout.addView(imageView);              
        }
    });
    final TextView textView=new TextView(this);
    textView.setId(200+i);
    String data="Click"+"\n"+"Show";
    textView.setText("click");


    newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());
    newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, imageView.getId());
    relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            relativeLayout.addView(textView, newParams);                
        }
    });
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView text=new TextView(this);
    text.setId(200+i);
    //String data="Click"+"\n"+"Show";
    text.setText("data");


    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView.getId());
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, textView.getId());
    relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            relativeLayout.addView(text, params);               
        }
    });
       linearLayout.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `LinearLayout` with orientation set to vertical?

Comment: how set orientation vertical for linear layout using code. Thanks now i got the output proper

Comment: first could you post image somewhere to show us what you wana achive, second for such cases ListView is better ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `LinearLayout` set to vertical orientation. I find them easier to use programmatically for things like this.

Below is a piece of sample code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

linearLayout.addView(childView1);
linearLayout.addView(childView2);
linearLayout.addView(childView3);

rootView.addView(linearLayout);
```

`childView1`, `childView2` and `childView3` will appear vertically.

Of course you will need to modify your code accordingly.